# onClick - Call Function from Another File

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a functionality.js file which is linked to the front-end, within here I want to click on a div(item1wrapper) and call a function from my index.js file.

Within this functionality.js file I append the div:

```
  socket.on('response', function (data) {
        if (msg.includes('totalPrice')) {    
        if (parsed.itemPrice.length === 1) {
            $('#messages').append($('<li id="messageclient">').append($(`
            <div id="message-cont" class="message-cont">     
            <div class="orderDetailsWrapper">
            <div class="detailsHeaderWrapper">
                <div class="orderNum"></div>
                <div class="customerName"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="textToCustomer">
            <p> Please click on the item you want to return</p>

           </div>

           <div class="itemBoxWrapper">
           <div id ="item1Wrapper" class="item1Wrapper" onclick="">
               <div class="item1Title"></div>
               <div class="item1Price"></div>
           </div>`
        )).append($('<div id="client-imgorder">')));
        $("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $("#messages")[0].scrollHeight }, 1000);

        $('.customerName').text('Customer name: ' + customerName);
        $('.orderNum').text('Order number: ' + orderNum);

        $('.item1Title').text('Item: ' + item1Title);
        $('.item1Price').text('Price: ' + item1Price);

        }
```

Module exports isnt working because it's linked to the front-end?

Here is my function within my index.js file:

```
 function oneCall() {
            itemId = itemIdArray[0];
            // matching API get 

            // getRefundCalc API post.
            console.log('ngrokurl' + ngrokUrl)
            console.log('domain' + domain)
            console.log('orderId' + orderId)
            console.log('itemId' + itemId)

            /*
            The Purchase date must be in the future
            */


            rp(optionsPOST1)
                .then(function (parsedBody) {
                    Match = parsedBody.Match;
                    if (Match) {
                        console.log('Match is true');

                        httpRequest.post(
                            `${ngrokUrl}/${domain}/${orderId}`,
                            {
                                json:
                                    {
                                        "line_items": [
                                            {
                                                "line_item_id": itemId, "quantity": 1
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                            },
                            function (error, resp, body) {
                                if (!error && resp.statusCode == 200) {
                                    console.log(body)

                                    response = responseToFrontEnd
                                    data = [details.chatuser, response]
                                    io.of('/main').to(socket.id).emit('response', data);

                                }
                                else {
                                    console.log('error' + error)
                                }
                            }
                        )
                        // include getRefundCalc within here
                    } else {
                        console.log('Match is false');
                        response = `I'm sorry but your item fell out of the refund policy. Please check the purchase date of your item or if it falls under the minimum price.`
                    }
                });
            }
```

Currently the "onclick" is empty because it wasnt working, when I click on that div in this functionality.js file I want to call that function! and it has to be outside of the functionality file as it requires node modules and needs to be within the socket function!

Comment: You have to include your `index.js` file in html file before using it

Comment: If i include the index.js file in my html then it comes up with errors

Comment: then i think solve the errors first (what errors?)

Comment: Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/index.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: I also once solved that problem but then having the index included stopped my functionality.js file from working